# How can I handle google popup and toast messages at the same time using Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

On my website when I log in, toaster messages will appear on the screen and at the same time a Google popup is generated.

How can I solve this problem?

After logging in I'm trying to click on my profile name and I want to select a drop down option. Can anyone help out with this?

Here is my [website.](http://www.lensnmirror.com/demo/mvp1-1/)

Comment: You have to handle one by one..you can not work on these two pop up at the time. If you are not using both the pop-ups.You may close it by using dismiss() function.  Otherwise, when you logged in with your profile just wait for some time & refresh the page by using driver.navigate().refresh();  Maybe it will close all the pop ups.

Comment: Add some more details; so far what you have tried & if possible add your HTML code & screen where you stuck.

Comment: add a screenshot of the pop-up message.

Comment: "How can I solve this problem?" - what problem?